# SmsManager not working. I have also included the permission in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sms

This code is not working.

I have included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>` in manifeast.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button send;
EditText phoneNo;
EditText sms;
SmsManager smsManager;

void sendMe(View view){
   sendMessage();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void sendMessage() {

    phoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNo);
    sms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sms);

    String Number = phoneNo.getText().toString();
    String message = sms.getText().toString();
    try {
       smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(Number, "Number", message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this,"SMS SEND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `android 3.4 version` there is not Android 3.4 at all. Did you mean *Android Studio*?

Comment: Also how exactly is it not working?

Comment: From where you are calling sendMe method?

Comment: i have used sendMEe as a onclick attribute in xml

Comment: basically the catch block is running

Comment: yes android studio version 3,4

Comment: @nihitkumar, you are giving both phno and msg right?

Comment: What exception is being thrown? Edit your original question and add the stacktrace and the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the exception, so I cannot be 100% sure, but I'm assuming that this iis failing due to the 2nd parameter in this call:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(Number, "Number", message, null, null);
```

The second parameter is the phone number of the SMSC. In general, unless you are using a custom SMSC you should just provide `null` as the second parameter to use the default SMSC.